# Absolute value of complex number (fraction) - different answers

Tags: complex-numbers, fractions, absolute-value

I want to take the absolute value of this fraction
$$
\frac{2-ixT}{2+ixT} \tag 1
$$
I know for a complex number $z=a+ib$ we have 
$$
\lvert z\rvert =\sqrt{ a^2+b^2}= \sqrt{(\Re\{ a\})^2 + (\Im \{b\})^2}\tag 2
$$
So
\begin{align}
\lvert \frac{2-ixT}{2+ixT}\rvert =
\sqrt{\frac{2^2+(xT)^2}{2^2+(xT)^2}} =\sqrt1 =1 \tag 3
\end{align}
But using the complex conjugate I get a different answer, why is that?

My attempt:
\begin{align}
\frac{2-ixT}{2+ixT}
&=
\frac{2-ixT}{2+ixT}\cdot \frac{2-ixT}{2-ixT}\\
&=\frac{(2-ixT)(2-ixT)}{4+x^2T^2}\\
&=
\frac{4+x^2T^2-i4Tx}{4+x^2T^2}\\
&=
\frac{4+x^2T^2}{4+x^2T^2}-i\frac{4Tx}{4+x^2T^2} \tag 4 \\
&=1-i\frac{4Tx}{4+x^2T^2} \tag 5
\end{align}
But using the absolute value $\lvert z\rvert =\sqrt{(\Re\{ a\})^2 + (\Im \{b\})^2}$ now gives
\begin{align}
\lvert
1-j\frac{4Tx}{4+x^2T^2}
\rvert
&= \sqrt{
1^2 + \bigg(\frac{4xT}{4+x^2T^2}\bigg)^2} \tag 6\\
&=\sqrt{
\frac{(4+x^2T^2)^2+(4xT)^2}{(4+x^2T^2)^2}
} \tag 7
\end{align}
I'm stuck here.

Answer (score 1):

$$\dfrac{a-ib}{a+ib}=\dfrac{(a-ib)^2}{a^2+b^2}=\dfrac{a^2-b^2+i(-2ab)}{a^2+b^2}$$

Now $$(a^2-b^2)^2+(-2ab)^2=(a^2-b^2)^2+4a^2b^2=(a^2+b^2)^2$$

Answer (score 1):

The third line in your answer is wrong. You will have $-x^{2}T^{2}$ instead of $x^{2}T^{2}$.

Once you make this correction you will get the answer as $1$ using the identity $(4-x^{2}T^{2})^{2}+16x^{2}T^{2}=(4+x^{2}T^{2})^{2}$

Answer (score 1):

Supposing $x, T \in \mathbb{R}$ and calling $z = \frac{2-i xT}{2+i x T}$ we have

$$
|z|=\sqrt{z\bar z} = \sqrt{ \frac{2-i xT}{2+i x T} \frac{2+i xT}{2-i x T}} = \sqrt{\frac{4+x^2T^2}{4+x^2T^2}}=1
$$